# Length of values does not match length of index - update dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I have got this code:

`df['newCol'] = [x if x in df['subject'] else np.NAN for x in myList]`

The error I receive is:
`ValueError: Length of values (97508) does not match length of index (100)`

What I'm trying to achieve is to check every item in `myList` (which is a list of str), and if one or more of them exist in `'subject'` column (which is a string column of variable lenght, that may or may not contain one or more item from `myList`) the `'newCol'` column is populated with a list of the matching items from `myList`; otherwise, in case of no match, Nan or an empty list.

The ValueError says that the lenght of values is different from lenght of index. What I can see is that 100 is the lenght of the df, while 97508 is the lenght of the df.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with pakpe's answer is the same as the logic in your original code. You say you want

> the 'newCol' column is populated with a **list** of the matching items
> from myList; otherwise, in case of no match, **Nan or an empty list**

Neither of your attempts account for that.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#initialize with blank list in newCol
testdata = [['Subject Test1 yes', []], ['Subject Test2 yes', []], ['Subject Test3 no', []]]
myList = ['yes', '2', 'random']

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(testdata, columns=['subject', 'newCol'])

# set column type of newCol as object to ensure it may contain a list of values
df['newCol'] = df['newCol'].astype('object')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for x in myList:
        if x in row['subject']:
            df.at[index, 'newCol'].append(x)

print(df)
```

Or if you want to fill with NaN you can do:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for x in range(len(myList)):
        if myList[x] in row['subject']:
            df.at[index, 'newCol'].append(myList[x])
        if x == len(myList)-1 and df.at[index, 'newCol'] == []:
            df.at[index, 'newCol'] = np.NAN
```

Output:

```
myList = ['yes', '2', 'random']

             subject    newCol
0  Subject Test1 yes     [yes]
1  Subject Test2 yes  [yes, 2]
2   Subject Test3 no     [nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject':['a','b','c','d','e']})
myList = ['c','e']
df['newCol'] = df[df['subject'].apply(lambda x: x in myList)]

print(df)
#
  subject newCol
0       a    NaN
1       b    NaN
2       c      c
3       d    NaN
4       e      e
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    for x in myList:
        if x in row.subject:
            df.iat[row.Index, 3].append(x)
```

since `itertuples()` ran faster that `iterrows()`.
However, given my dataframe is over 100,000 rows, and `myList` around 90,000 elements, it sill takes several minutes to execute.
I wish I could take benefit of some pandas vectorised method to improve performance, but so far I was unable to find a solution.
Any suggestion?